# An array is already a balanced B-tree, it is true?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

In one forum i was told that an array is already a balanced B-tree. How is it obtained ? maybe it is because the addition of the element in B tree has a fixed complexity ?

Comment: That probably depends on the programming language and how it defines array. Because in low-level programming languages like C, an array is simply mapped onto some memory as is.

Comment: Please post a link to where you got this information. Or provide more context. As written, your question is unclear.

Comment: I was told this in general chat from the site www.careercup.com

Comment: So ask the person who said so. SO isn't an explanation centre for random Internet noise.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that purely from a data-structure point of view, a **sorted** array `a` could be considered a B-tree with only one node. Namely, a B-tree of order greater than `length` of `a`. In such a case your root node would be the array `a` and since there would only be one node in the tree this root node would be a leaf node (which means it holds data and not just keys).

Such a B-tree would be balanced, because there is only one node at depth zero, which satisfies the requirement that in a balanced B-tree all leaf nodes must be at the same depth.

This would hold for a definition of order where a B-tree of order *m* is a B-tree in which every node has at most *m* children. That means nodes can contain at most *m*-1 keys (or elements in the case of leaf nodes).

Comment: A B-tree with one node, that's brilliant! haha

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about B-trees, but it is quite well known that sorted arrays have the structure of a balanced *binary search tree* embedded in them. It's in Knuth, etc.

Consider a section of the array with extent `low` to `high` (`high` pointing one-past-the-end as usual). The root of the tree is found at `(low + high) / 2` (let's call that index `mid`). The left subtree extends from `low` to `mid`. The right subtree extends from `mid + 1` to `high`. Zero-length extents correspond to leaves.

You can easily see that this must be a search tree: the elements to the left of mid are `<=` the root element because the array is sorted, and by definition those are exactly the elements in the left subtree. It works the same on the right.

You can also see that this implicit tree must be balanced, since the left and right subtrees are the same length on average.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this issue before in PHP. I insert 18000 log records into temp table and do querying and then I add these log records into array (it's associative) and do same querying again. The former tooks 0.006 second, whereas the latter tooks 0.51 seconds, averagely. So I think associative array is not b-treed at least in PHP.